# How can i restore an azure sql db if it is deleted?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database. There are backups,
but if a user accidentally deletes the database, how do I find the backups and restore if I can't see the database to select it in the Azure portal?
I have tried looking for the backups.

Answer (score 1):

Go the the Azure Sql Server where the database used to belong to in the Azure Portal. From there click on `Data management > Deleted databases` or `Data management > Backups > Showdatabases - Deleted (radio button)`. Assuming your database is still within your backup window it should be there with an option to restore it.

[image]